# ORM Django LEFT JOIN + GROUP BY

Tags: sql, django, group-by, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have following models in my Django project:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Membership(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    date_leaved = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And I want to create view on Django level which would perform that:

```
CREATE VIEW last_contract_expire AS
SELECT Player.name, MAX(Membership.date_leaved)
FROM player LEFT OUTER JOIN membership ON membership.player.id=player.id
GROUP BY player.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django currently does not support SQL views ([see this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3361)). Django also does not support SQL `GROUP BY` directly. Anyway, you could achieve it like this:

```
def last_contract_expire():
    return Player.objects.all().annotate(max_date_leaved=Max('membership__date_leaved'))
```

This will return all players and each player will have attributes `name` and `max_date_leaved`. Hope this helps